# How to workaround/prevent hotkey firing when key is released

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to get a hotkey to perform two functions - one if it is pressed quickly, below a time threshold (400ms in my code), and another if the key is held for longer than that time.

I do want it to fire the short press function immediately when the key is lifted, ie not to wait until 400ms is up.

Here's the code I've come up with:

```
LongPress := 400
F22::{
Loop
    {
    if (A_TimeSinceThisHotkey > LongPress) {
            ToolTip("LONG press detected - " . A_TimeSinceThisHotkey . "ms")
            break
        }
    if not GetKeyState(A_ThisHotkey, "P") {
            ToolTip("SHORT press detected - " . A_TimeSinceThisHotkey . "ms")
            break 
        }
    }

    return
}
```

I'm seeing two types of unexpected behavior that I would like to prevent.

1. When I release the hotkey, it often shows a short press detected with a very short time, sometimes 0ms. I tried adding `if not GetKeyState(A_ThisHotkey, "P") return` before the loop, which I would have hoped to just exit the hotkey function immediately when it's activated on key release, but that didn't change the behavior.
2. When I'm holding the hotkey down for a very long time, it seems to fire the "long press detected" over and over, ie I see "LONG press detected" with a changing number of ms afterwards, 402ms, 410ms, etc.

I want the hotkey to fire only once for each press of the hotkey, either a short or a long press, but not over and over, and also not to fire the extra short press when the key is released.

How can I achieve both of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @user3419297 for the hint to use `Keywait`. I'm using ahk v2 so had to convert it a bit.

Here's the final code I went with:

```
LongPress := 0.3 ; 300ms

F22::{
    waitvar := (Keywait(A_ThisHotkey, "T" LongPress)) ; waits 0.3 seconds maximally for F22 to be released
    if waitvar
    {
        ToolTip("waitvar = " waitvar "`n" "SHORT press detected: " . A_TimeSinceThisHotkey . " ms")
        SetTimer () => ToolTip(), -2000 ; remove the ToolTip
    }
    else
        ToolTip("waitvar = " waitvar "`nLONG press detected: " A_TimeSinceThisHotkey " ms")
        SetTimer () => ToolTip(), -2000 ; remove the ToolTip
    KeyWait A_ThisHotkey  ; waits for F22 to be released (stops key repeat from retriggering)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#Requires AutoHotkey v1.1.33

LongPress := 0.4 ; 400ms

$F22::
Keywait F22, T%LongPress% ; waits 0.4 seconds maximally for F22 to be released
if ErrorLevel     ; pressed for above that time
{
     KeyWait F22  ; waits for F22 to be released
     ToolTip, LONG press detected: %A_TimeSinceThisHotkey% ms
}
else
     ToolTip, SHORT press detected: %A_TimeSinceThisHotkey% ms
return
```

Comment: Thanks! The `KeyWait F22` needs to be immediately before `return` to avoid retriggering from key repeat. Also I use ahk v2. I've added another answer with my working code.